# Is there any data on how many users' IP addresses never look at their questions again?

Tags: support, new-users, statistics, traffic

Looking at a few random questions on Parenting, I noticed that many one-question users are never seen later than a few minutes after their questions were posted (confusingly, due to how the "seen" metric works, some are last seen *before* their question was posted).

On Science Fiction & Fantasy, the same thing happens on a huge number of story-identification questions—a user posts one question and is never seen again.

I know that Stack Exchange has a lot of data on users for SEDE queries, ads, etc.

**Is there any data on how many users never visit their single question ever again, including non-logged-in visits from their IP addresses?**

Comment: Many people use dynamic IPs so I guess it would be difficult to track them if it changes every 24h or so.

Comment: @ChristineH.Richards Yes, it’d be a tough statistic, but still interesting.

Comment: Maybe to check (last question asked/edit time <= user's last seen time) && (accpeted answer == null)

Comment: Your questions are a relief! Thank you for making the site feel normal :)

Comment: @Yvette no problem, I always have enough problems with the site to complain about without the specific drama currently playing out 

Comment: I think you would need to find a staff member to get you this data, as IP adres isnt a publicly accesible thing, and rightfully so. Seeing that staff is quite occupied at the moment you should at least expect to wait 6-8 time units for an answer, if any.

Comment: @Sonic why remove that tag?

Comment: I didn't feel that that was a necessary differentiation, and I felt that it was conveyed by the other tags being used. As this was the only question using it, I removed it.